# Why isn't the for loop working in this html page?

Tags: python, html, flask

So I have this python for loop in html which would display all of the users in my sqlite3 file.

```
<body>
{% block title %} View All Users {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% for item in values %}
        <p>svid: {{item.user_svid}}, balance: {{item.balance}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

The main Python code for the users page:

```
@app.route("/users/")
def user_list():
    return render_template("users.html", values=users.query.all)
```

However, I get this error and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

```
  File "/Users/danish/Desktop/Marketplace/templates/users.html", line 44, in top-level template code
    {% block content %}
  File "/Users/danish/Desktop/Marketplace/templates/users.html", line 45, in block "content"
    {% for item in values: %}
TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable
```

Comment: What do you think `TypeError` means? What do you think a `'method' object` is? What do you think it means for something to be `iterable`? Try looking up these terms, and then look closely at how `values` is determined.

Answer (score 1):

Missing parenthesis in `query.all`

```
@app.route("/users/")
def user_list():
    myusers = users.query.all()
    return render_template("users.html", values=myusers)
```